# how to calculate sum of numbers in a string in postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql

```
1^1^1^5^1|1^1|1^1
```

Is there a simple way to add all above numbers in postgresql. I would like to write a function that takes above string and outputs 13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the function [`regexp_split_to_table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)

```
SELECT sum(s::int) 
  FROM regexp_split_to_table('1^1^1^5^1|1^1|1^1','\D') as s
```

Here you use the regex `\D` to split on everything that is **not** a digit, leaving you with the digits (read more about [postgres regex](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)), which you then sum as integers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option if you are using Postgre 9.3 or later:

```
SELECT SUM(s.num::int) AS sum
FROM your_table t, unnest(string_to_array(replace(t.col::text, '|', '^'), '^')) s(num);
```

### Demo

But the better long term fix would be to avoid such SQL olympics, and instead to normalize your data.  Ideally each number you want to sum should be in a separate record, which is what the above query actually does to generate the sum.